# Show Multiple Filter Options of a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to show multiple filter options on one pivot table? In this example it's counting the amount of smokers per region based on the filter of sex. Can I show both the male and female options in the same pivot table at the same time (so 2 columns for smokers: one male, one female)? or do I have to click the drop down every time?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that result you should drag the Sex column from Filters area to the Columns area (Where you see a column called "Type" in the image below).

[image: Pivot table config screen]

This should create as many columns as different values you have in your "Sex" column of your dataset.